# JSON output of a JAX-WS webservice?

Tags: java, json, spring, cxf, jax-ws

Is it possible that a `jax-ws` `soap-webservice` can output `json` format instead of `xml`?

```
@Component
@WebService
public class HRSService {

    @WebMethod
    public String test(String value) {
        return value; //returned as XML. JSON possible?
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't think so. SOAP protocol have many featurs - WS-security, for example. I don't know haw it can work with JSON onstead of XML. But of course you can write some REST service and do marshalling as you want.

Comment: It might be possible with CXF, but with some drawbacks explained here: http://cxf.apache.org/docs/jax-rs-and-jax-ws.html

Comment: It should be possible. JAXB is capable of marshalling and unmarshalling JSON using the Moxy implementation. I can't say it'll work smoothly with an `@WebService`, which is quite high-level, but with an `@WebServiceProvider`, it should be quite straightforward. Another option would be the [`@UsesJaxbContext`](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5627173/1530938) with `@WebService`. Ultimately, if you're in control of the JAXBContext, you should be able to pull this off

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JAX-WS For Json request and response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32990357/jax-ws-for-json-request-and-response)

Comment: @Vadzim If you are suggesting duplicates, make sure that the question actually has worthwhile answers (and not only link-only answers). I have reversed the direction of the vote.

Answer (score 5):

Apparently it's possible by following the instructions indicated at [https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/json/ (Archive version)](https://web.archive.org/web/20160702062228/https://jax-ws-commons.java.net/json/)

Summing up:

```
@BindingType(JSONBindingID.JSON_BINDING)
public class MyService {

    public Book get(@WebParam(name="id") int id) {
        Book b = new Book();
        b.id = id;
        return b;
    }

    public static final class Book {
        public int id = 1;
        public String title = "Java";
    }
}
```

You just need `jaxws-json.jar` in your `WEB-INF/lib` for this to work.

I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

This is late. I recently returned to programming in Java, but for those who will be visiting this page in the future. The example in the JAXWS metro documents works only in javascript. I used the following together with JSONObject:

```
@WebServiceProvider
@ServiceMode(value = Service.Mode.MESSAGE)
@BindingType(value=HTTPBinding.HTTP_BINDING)
```

then implement Provider(DataSource), as in example:

```
public class clazz implements Provider<DataSource>
{ ...

    @Override
    public DataSource invoke(DataSource arg)
    { 
        ...
        String emsg = "Request Parameter Error.";
        String sret = create_error_response(emsg);

        return getDataSource(sret);
    }
}

private DataSource getDataSource(String sret)
{
    ByteArrayDataSource ds = new ByteArrayDataSource(sret.getBytes(), "application/json");
    return ds;
}

public String create_error_response(String msg)
{
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    json.put("success", new Boolean(false));
    json.put("message", msg);
    return json.toString();
}
```